# How to stored data in WPF MVVM app without database?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have started writing one application using WPF and encountered the problem of is it possible to stored data in MVVM without database or XML files?

The data don't need to be saved after close program so should I store they in ViewModel or there is any better way to do it?

Comment: In the data layer you have a repository for the data. It can be SQL-, XML- or InMemory-Based (or even whaterever based). For the app there is no difference, it is just the repository implementation

Comment: either  VM or in a separate static class.

Comment: @Steve Both are anti-patterns

Comment: @SirRufo why so? depends on the type of data I would say VM might be the perfect place to do so

Comment: @Steve VM is not the data layer, static class for that kind of work is like singleton which is well known as anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would create a Model class for the information that needs to be stored. The ViewModel would reference this, and the View would display.

Like

```
public class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public Color AccentColor {get;set;} //Implement your callback functions ...
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And, when the time comes that you choose to implement an xml saver, you can easily do it via applying the SerializableAttribute attribute.

Hope this helped, and hope that I understood your problem correctly.